# Having a remote team to connect to a service with a fixed IP

Tags: networking, proxy, ip

I belong to a team of several people, divided throughout the world.

We are building software for a certain platform, lets call it "Platform S". To develop for this platform there are 2 resources that are necessary. One is the SDK, which can be installed only using certain installer, that connects directly with the Platform S centrail server, and install it in out machine. The other resource is the developer website, where people post their questions and doubts about the SDK and hardware it operates on itself.

The problem comes that to connect to these resources, both the forums and to download/update the SDK, I need to have **always** the same IP address.

To solve this problem, I initially created a server with a fixed IP and installed proxy software in it, so that we could configure our local machines to connect to the proxy, and all have the same IP address.

Of course, to avoid that this proxy were used with nefarious purposes by hackers, and others, I protected the proxy with a password. When accessing the forums, this was no problem, as the browser opened a small dialogue window, to ask me for the user and password. **But** the installer that is in charge of installing/updating the SDK does not offer me this dialogue window. The last time, I disabled the password for a while, since SDK updating is not a task that one does that often, but after just a couple hours, I already got a notice from my server provider to warn me that the server was being used for malicious purposes. So that meant that this solution was not appropiate.

What approach could I take to solve my problem? Is the proxy idea the wrong way to go?